# How to get the container with panther

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-panther

Im trying to get the container in my testcase.

```
$client = self::createPantherClient()->getContainer()
```

&

```
Error : Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::getContainer()
```

So how do you get the container within a Panther test client?

Comment: Why do you need container? To retrieve services?

Comment: Yes, to retrieve a 3rd party service, which can not be fetched by using autowire nor by class name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that if you cannot autowire it, you can retrieve it.

By the way, you can go like this

```
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
```

Should work

Comment: If you create the container with the "normal" client, panther is creating its own container, and not possible to do what I need.